# jquery error g.handle.h

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I am running into a funny error when I publish my web application. Note this doesn't happen on all the computers. Only on the selected few computers. I am using Chorme as the browser and have verified that two different computers have the same browser version. Ajax Post works fine on one computer and the other it doesn't.

I point to the latest jQuery file available at google.

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery
https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery-ui

This is the error I am getting when a Ajax Post is made:
[image: Console View]

Comment: The 500 Internal Server Error is related to the page that you're posting to. The Ajax is working properly.

Comment: Yes. On my local computer when Ajax call is made, it loads a partial view successfully without any errors.

Comment: So there is something wrong on your production server. The 500 Internal Server Error is not from the Ajax.

Comment: Why would the server deliver the partial view on one instance and not on the other?

Comment: Is one production and the other development? There might be differences between the two. What is supposed to be running on the server?

Comment: server is amazon ec2 that running IIS 7 on Server 2008. Development is Windows 7 running IIS 7.

Comment: Then there are bound to be some differences. It would appear that production is not running your chosen scripting method, be it PHP, ASP or whatever.